# Python Get Sibling inside JSON Structure

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Lets say I am given the ***goal*** and want the ***target***. How would you iterate thru this and get the desired target value (given e.g. A1) in a one liner. I get the data from the file without problems by using `json.load(json_data)`

#### The JSON

```
{
  "conservative": {
    "goal": "A1",
    "target" : 60000,
    "oneoff": 6000,
    "regular": 600
  },
  "moderate": {
    "goal": "A2",
    "target": 70000,
    "oneoff": 7000,
    "regular": 710
  },
  "optimistic": {
    "goal": "A3",
    "target": 80000,
    "oneoff": 8000,
    "regular": 800
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you can try using following to get list of target that may match input values (*if single value expected you can simply put* `[0]` *to get single items from the list*). E.g. with `goal_val = 'A1'`:

```
target = [val['target'] for _, val in my_data.items() if val['goal'] == goal_val]
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by using `next()` with a generator expression, instead of a list comprehension, to avoid any further iteration after the correct goal is found.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple one-line solution:

```
d = {
  "conservative": {
    "goal": "A1",
    "target" : 60000,
    "oneoff": 6000,
    "regular": 600
  },
  "moderate": {
    "goal": "A2",
    "target": 70000,
    "oneoff": 7000,
    "regular": 710
  },
  "optimistic": {
    "goal": "A3",
    "target": 80000,
    "oneoff": 8000,
    "regular": 800
  }
}

goal = "A1" # <-- Your goal here

target = next(v['target'] for _, v in d.items() if v['goal'] == goal)
# target == 60000
```

This uses an generator expression to avoid executing any more iterations than necessary. `next()` will make sure you only get a single value returned.

This could easily be modified to return the complete matched dictionary instead:

```
match = next(v for k, v in d.items() if v['goal'] == goal)
# match == {"goal": "A1", target: 60000, ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code my friend:

```py
data = {
  "conservative": {
    "goal": "A1",
    "target" : 60000,
    "oneoff": 6000,
    "regular": 600
  },
  "moderate": {
    "goal": "A2",
    "target": 70000,
    "oneoff": 7000,
    "regular": 710
  },
  "optimistic": {
    "goal": "A3",
    "target": 80000,
    "oneoff": 8000,
    "regular": 800
  }
}

goal_required = 'A1'

for obj in data:
    if data[obj]['goal'] == goal_required:
        target = data[obj]['target']
        print("Object {} with the goal {} needs a target of {}".format(obj, goal_required, target))
```

Which gives the output:

`Object conservative with the goal A1 needs a target of 60000`